# Статические свойства и наследование в PHP

Tags: php, архитектура, наследование

Хотелось бы услышать мнение сообщества по поводу правильного оформления классов при наследовании.
Чтобы не лить воду, перейду сразу к примеру.
Есть базовый класс:

```
<?php
abstract class Animal 
{
    public static function classes()
    {
        return [
            Dog::TYPE_ID => Dog::class,
            Cat::TYPE_ID => Cat::class,
        ];
    }

    public function getTypeId()
    {
        return static::TYPE_ID;
    }

    public function getTypeAlias()
    {
        return static::TYPE_ALIAS;
    }

    public function getTypeTitle()
    {
        return static::TYPE_TITLE;
    }
}
```

Есть классы-наследники:

```
<?php
class Dog extends Animal 
{
    const TYPE_ID = 1;
    const TYPE_ALIAS = 'dog';
    const TYPE_TITLE = 'Собака';

    // Dog related methods
    public function sayWoof() {}
}
class Cat extends Animal
{
    const TYPE_ID = 2;
    const TYPE_ALIAS = 'cat';
    const TYPE_TITLE = 'Кошка';

    // Cat related methods
    public function sayMeow() {}
}
```

То есть, допустим, у нас есть некий журнал учета животных в приюте. Все записи о животных хранятся в одной таблице БД. В этой таблице есть поле INT `type_id`, в котором хранится тип животного и на основе которого, при извлечении данных, инстанцируются соответствующие классы (Single Table Inheritance).

Так вот, собственно, что меня смутило. Я использовал константы для определения свойств в дочерних классах - вроде бы свойства классов постоянные и неизменяемые, НО:
1. В абстрактном классе Animal, PhpStorm ругается - мол, нет таких констант в данном классе. Добавление констант-пустышек, только лишь бы удовлетворить IDE, кажется не очень хорошей идеей.
2. Иногда, при использовании констант для таких целей, получается их переопределение (override) в дочерних классах, а это тоже, как я читал на StackOverflow, не очень хорошая практика. Типа константа должна быть константой).

Но есть и определенные плюсы:
1. Можно обратиться к свойствам классов без создания экземпляра. Например, чтобы получит список классов всех видов животных в БД (как в методе `Animal::classes()`).
2. Константы не 'висят' в самом экземпляре класса, например если сделать `var_dump(new Dog())`, в отличии от свойств класса. Может, даже, это как-то поможет в экономии памяти если свойств много (я предполагаю из сравнения с prototype в JS).
3. Для глаза как-то чище и приятнее код.

Расскажите свое мнение по этому поводу. Может лучше использовать статические свойства? Или можете предложить свои примеры решения таких ситуаций?

Comment: То есть класс животного уже знает о том кто его будет наследовать? А зачем? Это нарушает основной принцип наследования - по-моему проще определить абстрактную функцию getType и заменить ее в наследуемых классах, либо не использовать константу TYPE_ID а переменную без права записи (protected)

Comment: Ну у меня мысль такая - мне необходимо где-то определить список всех доступных для создания классов животных, чтобы, например, в интерфейсе приложения вывести выпадающий список с доступными для добавления животными "Добавить -> Новую кошку" Чтобы не заводить отдельный класс для этого, разместил этот список в абстрактном родителе. Но это не самая главная мысль моего вопроса. Я хотел бы узнать, как лучше всего оформить свойство класса, которое является общим для всех экземпляров этого класса и должно быть доступно как из статического, так и из динамического контекста?

Comment: Это можно выяснить динамически (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671398/get-all-defined-classes-of-a-parent-class-in-php) - наследников класса.

Comment: можно регать через вызов статического метода после определени класса.. обычно такое можно сделать в статическом конструкторе, но почему то в пхп такого нет.

Comment: @ЮрийБезруков вы где тут на странице _статистические_ нашли?